# how to install .net framework 4.0 on win 10

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, installation, windows-10, development-environment

- when I open project through Visual Studio 2010,it shows that I need .net framework 4.0 :
  [image]
- But when I install .net framework 4.0,shows it is already installed : 
  [image]

***translation above:**

> 1. Microsoft .NET Framework 4 is already included in this operating
>      system. You do not need to install the .NET Framework 4
>      redistributable.
> 2. .NET Framework 4 (included) and above is already installed on this
>      computer.

how can I fix this? very thanks!

Comment: You need to install Windows SDK, which contains .NET Framework 4.0 SDK and those referenced assemblies. That's different from .NET Framework itself.

Comment: @LexLi thanks! It's work after Windows SDK install